# Find a value if $q $ in order for $y+q-x=0 $to be tangent of function$ -3x^2 -5x +1$

Tags: calculus

I have been having trouble with this assignment for a while and still can't seem to get a hang of it.
The obvious answer would be to take a first derivative of function, geometrically speaking a tangent line of entire function, and then use

> b
>   from 
>   y = mx + b
>   as my q.

But here comes the first issue because the format of answers doesn't fit. 
Expected answer lacks coefficient, assuming that we can get pass that here comes another problem.

Derivative of my function is

> y=-6x-5

Comparing to expected format of answer

> y = x - q

One would expect, if dismissing the coefficient, the answer to be 5.
However the answer required is -4.

There must be something I am missing but so far I had no luck identifying it.

For clarity, no point/points are provided in the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** The slope of your tangent line $y+q-x=0$ is $1$. You already have the formula for the slope of the quadratic curve. Find where those two slopes are equal, giving you the $x$-coordinate of the point of tangency. Find the value of $q$ that actually makes the line a tangent at that point.

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes sense. Marking it as the answer.